# What can happen if you dont increase your OSGi Versionnumber?

Tags: osgi, cxf, osgi-bundle

I am creating some remote services with apache CXF (dosgi) and zookeeper as my discoery mechanism in an Equinox environment.
At the beginning i created a Webservice without parameters. Everything worked well. After that I wanted to add parameters to my webservice. So I extended my Interface and built all my bundles new. But I didn't increase the versionnumber.
After reinstalling all the bundles (Interface, service, consumer) the consumer didn't find the webservice anymore.
I figured out that there was somewhere still the old webservice without the parameters. I even tried to restart zookeeper and equinox without success.
It only worked again after increasing the versionnumber of my bundles.
So what happens internal when (un)installing a bundle? Will it be kept somewhere? Can someone explain what exactly happend to me?

Comment: I don't know about equinox, but afaik most osgi frameworks do use a cache to store bundles.

Comment: "After reinstalling all the bundles": How do you re-install your bundles?

Comment: in the osgi console i typed `uninstall XX` and `install file:xxxxxx`. Since I didnt had a versionnumber eclipse added a timestamp to the filename.

Comment: You probably want to run the refresh command after you install the new bundles. And make sure to start the new bundles too.

Comment: `refresh` comand solved it. Thanks